# C#: вызов WaitForm во время выполнения метода

Tags: c#

Начальные условия:
Есть форма на которой много элементов управления (например кнопок). При нажатии кнопки запускается действие, в моем случае, в основную форму встраивается `UserControl`. Во время выполнения этого действия отображается `WaitForm` (форма "ожидания").

```
 private void accordionControlElement1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            splashScreenManager1.ShowWaitForm();//Открытие формы ожидания
            c_personnel c_Personnel = new c_personnel();
            c_Personnel.Show();
            CreatePage(c_Personnel, (sender as AccordionControlElement).Text, c_Personnel.Name);
            splashScreenManager1.CloseWaitForm();//Закрытие формы ожидания
        }
```

Вопрос: Так как в форме довольно много кнопок, есть ли возможность не прописывать для каждой кнопки открытие закрытие `WaitForm`, а создать какой-либо универсальный метод, который  бы  автоматом запускал отображение `WaitForm`?

Comment: Так подписываете один обработчик на все кнопки и готово

Comment: @aepot А если там на кнопках ещё логика есть? :))

Comment: @Виктор на Click можно повесить более 1 обработчика.